# Show a div if only google ad is present

Tags: javascript, html, google-dfp

Using javascript, I need to display a DIV but only if it contains a Google Ad.  Here's the code I'm working with via Google:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-1346196436229-0'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1346196436229-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

The DIV ID in the above code was generated by Google for the ad slot.

Any thoughts or directions I can get?  Admittedly I'm pretty weak in the javascripting world so please be gentle. :)

Comment: What is the full context of the problem? What are the other possible scenarios in your situation? i.e. what else can the div potentially contain?

Comment: The div needs to ONLY show if a google ad is detected.  The only other things in the div will be styling.  Pretty basic it seems to me than I'm javascript 'challenged'.

Comment: Two years after this was answered, it's being flagged as too broad?  I thought it was specific -- I needed to know how to display a div if a Google ad was present.  How much more specific do I need to be?

Comment: @86Stang Agree, I dont see how this could be too broad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just include this tag in your header code like so.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.defineSlot('AdSlot-name', [AdSize], 
'div-gpt-ad-1346196436229-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
</script>
```

The tag you add is:

```
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about this... you could change the way of thinking about this and hide the div if there is not an ad using the [collapseEmptyDivs](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1650154&expand=pubservice_details#collapseemptydivs) setting in the DFP API.

If you absolutely must start with a hidden div and then only show it if it contains an ad it is a little more complicated... if you are using jQuery on your page check out the [plugin](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) I wrote.

The other answers are nearly correct but its not quite as simple as checking for an iframe... in my experience an iframe will be present regardless of whether an ad is actually there to be displayed or not. Checking for an iframe on page load is also not going to work because often the ads will be rendered after page load.

You need to hook into the DFP script and check on the status of the ads once renderEnded has been fired... using the linked plugin above you have two callbacks which can easily do this... the plugin also adds a class to the ad unit div of display-block or display-none depending on whether an ad was found or not... these can then easily be used to hide or show a div with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no creative DoubleClick simply outputs an empty string. I'm counting the number of children in the div containing the ad and hiding based on that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($('#ad-id').children().length < 5)
    {
        $('#ad-id').hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the other response, you can use jQuery to check the element's content for an iframe

```
if($('#div-gpt-ad-1346196436229-0').has('iframe'))
  $('#div-gpt-ad-1346196436229-0').show
```

Comment: How would this code tie in with the one I posted above? I'm not seeing the overarching logic I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I had an issue in IE with ads loading a blank white background iframe when failing to get an ad. The following code handles the op issue + the IE fix, you must have collapseEmtpyDivs set to true and start out with the adunit elements initially showing:

```
if( $(adUnit).css("display") == "none"  || $(adUnit).hasClass("display-none") )
    $(adUnit).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be a way to do something OTHER than hide or show the ad served container div. I know this is off topic, but what if the presence of the ad determines other things on the page, like whether an item should be positioned absolutely, or floated etc...
In my case, i have a video player over the top of an ad served slot, which i want to change the background of, only if an ad is PRESENT.
...
pretty hacky way to do it, it seems like there *should* be a callback or response request to determine this after display() finishes... success / fali etc.

Answer (score -1):

basically it is simple

by their ads, google is using a whole html doc, and an iframe, so page laod done, you can just check if the div is containing the 'html' or 'iframe' tag and show it if yes

hope it helps

*and i recomend to put the ads in holder diws with predefined id-s

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: When the paged is loaded, the div is basically empty.
After the page has been loaded, the div in question is being populated by ads via google js.

So you check for some constant that can be found in every google ad.

This is the iframe tag.

Hence, if you check the content of your target div with js after page load for the iframe tang, and js returns a false, it means the google ad has not been loaded into the div, so you hide the div, or keep it hidden.

If it is returning true, you change the divs visibility to show and its done.

Comment: Based on what you said, do you have some code bits to get me started in the right direction?  Again -- I'm javascript challenged. :)

Comment: Google puts the iframe there, even if no ad is flighted, so you can get a big, white box where an ad would normally be. Is there a way to fix that?